# Set property value into JSF code

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm interested how I can set value into JSF page. For example something like this.

```
itemValue="#{ud.datacenterId = datacenters.datacenterid}"
```

How I can directly assign the value of datacenters.datacenterid into ud.datacenterId? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that with an action(listener) method.

E.g.

```
<h:commandButton ... action="#{ud.setDatacenterId(datacenters.datacenterid)}" />
```

or

```
<h:commandButton ... actionListener="#{ud.setDatacenterId(datacenters.datacenterid)}" />
```

or

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{ud.datacenterId}" value="#{datacenters.datacenterid}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

or

```
<h:commandButton ...>
    <f:ajax listener="#{ud.setDatacenterId(datacenters.datacenterid)}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

etc.

If your follow-up question is actually "How to invoke it during page load?", then you actually have a different question. Based on your question history, you're using PrimeFaces. Look at [`<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true">`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/remoteCommand.jsf) then. I would still only wonder if this all is [really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) the right solution to the concrete functional requirement which you've had in mind.